# How to fill picker with a list

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am updating older code but part of it must stay the same. I have now picker that needs to be filled with list. 
My list

```
public List<TimeoutBetweenSentences> FillTimoutOptions()
        {
            var newListTimeoutBetweenSentenceses = new List<TimeoutBetweenSentences>()
            {
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 0,
                    Text = "+ 0 sekund",
                    Value = 0
                },
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 1,
                    Text = "+ 1 sekunda",
                    Value = 1
                },
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 2,
                    Text = "+ 2 sekundy",
                    Value = 2
                },
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 3,
                    Text = "+ 3 sekundy",
                    Value = 3
                },
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 4,
                    Text = "+ 4 sekundy",
                    Value = 4
                },
                new TimeoutBetweenSentences()
                {
                    Position = 5,
                    Text = "+ 5 sekund",
                    Value = 5
                },
            };

            return newListTimeoutBetweenSentenceses;
        }

  List<TimeoutBetweenSentences> allOptions = FillTimoutOptions();
            sentencePausesStepper.Items.Add(allOptions.Select(m => m.Text).ToList().ToString());
```

however this displays just as "System collections" DO zou have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is adding an entire list as ONE element

```
sentencePausesStepper.Items.Add(allOptions.Select(m => m.Text).ToList().ToString());
```

to add elements of one list to another, use AddRange instead

```
sentencePausesStepper.Items.AddRange(allOptions.Select(m => m.Text).ToList().ToString());
```

or better, do this

```
sentencePausesStepper.ItemsSource = allOptions;
sentencePausesStepper.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Text");
```

Comment: thanks, AddRange was not  an option only Add, working but the second way works fine. Thanks